# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

**I am getting Following Error while using apache poi dependency.**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:538)
    org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1539)
    org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
    com.bonrix.common.test.Excel.sajan(Excel.java:62)


         <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

```
    // Create a blank sheet 
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("student Details"); 

    // This data needs to be written (Object[]) 
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>(); 
    data.put("1", new Object[]{ "ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME" }); 
    data.put("2", new Object[]{ 1, "Pankaj", "Kumar" }); 
    data.put("3", new Object[]{ 2, "Prakashni", "Yadav" }); 
    data.put("4", new Object[]{ 3, "Ayan", "Mondal" }); 
    data.put("5", new Object[]{ 4, "Virat", "kohli" }); 

    // Iterate over data and write to sheet 
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet(); 
    int rownum = 0; 
    for (String key : keyset) { 
        // this creates a new row in the sheet 
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++); 
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key); 
        int cellnum = 0; 
        for (Object obj : objArr) { 
            // this line creates a cell in the next column of that row 
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++); 
            if (obj instanceof String) 
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj); 
            else if (obj instanceof Integer) 
                cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj); 
        } 
    } 
    try { 
        // this Writes the workbook gfgcontribute 
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://gfgcontribute.xlsx")); 
        workbook.write(out); 
        out.close(); 
        System.out.println("gfgcontribute.xlsx written successfully on disk."); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

It's Work fine while running as java application but in web app Spring Controller it's shows error.
I tried different version of  poi. But Still its shows Error.
I think it's conflict with other java which are added into my porm.xml file.
I am using java spring for my project.
I also referred https://stackoverflow.com/ from the solution, but any solution is not worked for me.
in other project i used apache poi 3.5 which is working fine for me but in this case it's not working, is there any solution for this problem?
Can i know what is the problem with my code or dependency which are used by me. 
i tried my best but i did not solved this error.

Comment: If that `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is thrown on runtime, there must be a `org.apache.poi.util.POILogger` class in class path other than on compile time. This occurs if there are `poi` `jar`s from different versions in class path. See first [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) for how to check. Check for where `org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.class` came from.

Answer (score 0):

Maven downloads all dependencies to a folder .m2/repository in the user's home directory (i.e. C:\users[your user name].m2\repository on Windows. When you delete this folder, Maven creates the folder and downloads the dependencies for the projects you're building from then on. take correct version which is run your application in pom.xml

Comment: can you please suggest correct version bacause i  tried 3 versions.

Comment: which version you're used

Comment: Why are you suggesting such ancient versions, which have known bugs and security issues? Why not suggest the latest stable supported version?

Comment: Gagravarr i used  <poi-version>4.1.2</poi-version> but i got an error,  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but interface was expected